# DFDL Parser-IIB(IBM INtegration Bus)

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, dfdl

I have a dfdl configured for HTTPInput node which receives data from HTTP POST.
I get the data in encoded format.
ex:

```
                 %2412%2C843.40    

                10%2F01%2F2014
```

The equivalent values are $12,843.40 and 10/01/2014

Is there any option in DFDL to make the incoming hexa values parse into normal values as like above

Comment: I think this [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/df20091_.htm) will answer your question

Comment: as mentiond in that article i changes all properties to dfdl_expression but nothing worked

Comment: i figured the java function that can be used is URLDecode.
Is there any equivalent function in ESQL to achieve the same.